# bootstrap-table not rendering upon updating model in Angular

Tags: angularjs, bootstrap-table

Hi I am not able to render table using bootstrap-table and angular. here is my code, I think I need to call bootstrap-table init method in angular ajax call. Can some one guide me on how to do this..?

```js
angular
  .module('reports')
  .controller(
    'ReportCtrl',
    [
      '$scope',
      '$http',
      'ngProgress',
      function($scope, $http, ngProgress) {
       var vm = this;
       vm.mdp = {};
       vm.mdp.data = [];
       vm.mdp.columns = [];
       
       $scope.submit = function() {
        
        var report = $scope.tab;
                               $http.post('/reports/cmd/getData', {
         report : report,
         date : createdAfter
        }).success(function(data) {
                                 vm.mdp.data = data;
          $.each(data[0], function(key, value){
           vm.mdp.columns.push(key);
          });
                                 }).error(function(error) {
         alert(error);
         
        });
        

       };

      } ]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.15/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="mdp" class="panel" ng-controller="ReportCtrl as report" ng-show="panel.isSelected('mdp')">
 <table data-toggle="table" data-show-columns="true" data-search="true" data-show-export="true" data-pagination="true" data-height="299">
     <thead>
     <tr>
     
     <th ng-repeat="c in report.mdp.columns" data-field= {{c}} >{{ c }}</th>
     
        
     </tr>
     </thead>
     <tr ng-repeat="r in report.mdp.data">
     
      <td ng-repeat="c in report.mdp.columns">{{ r[c] }}</td>
  </tr>
     
  </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Integrating Bootstrap Table with Angular is solved here:

1. https://github.com/wenzhixin/bootstrap-table/issues/165
2. https://github.com/AkramKamal/bootstrap-table-examples/tree/master/integrate

I have some minor changes in my implementation of this solution which I will upload to Github / JSFiddle shortly. But the links above will allow you to get going.